# base64 image and laravel file input

Tags: php, file-upload, laravel-4

I'm using [croppic](http://www.croppic.net/) inline mode image preview, So i can do the changes first and upload. Problem is when I upload, its passing as `base64` image instead of`$_FILES`.

I cannot do laravel default `getClientOriginalExtension` or `move` operation.

Is there anyway to do this.

PS: I'm currently trying [intervention](http://image.intervention.io/) package.

**Update**
Code sample. [github](https://github.com/sconsult/croppic/blob/master/img_crop_to_file.php)

Comment: Are you able to post a code sample for how you are doing this with croppic?

Answer (score -2):

append a base64 decode method, and you can perform the usual methods:

```
$new_image = base64_decode($base64_image);
```

Comment: ```getClientOriginalExtension``` doesn't work after apply ```base64_decode```: ```FatalThrowableError```